# how to change border color due to current page in css

Tags: html, css

I need to make the border red when its the current page , hope it clear when click on phone border must be red whole time in same page and when click for email border must be red and the phone return back with black color.

```css
.EPbutton{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: did you try using javascript or jquery?

Comment: You cant do that without any server side scripting except if you have an SPA like Angular or so. Basically you would add a class to the current menu item server-side and then style that class diffrently. But you cant do that with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PHP, you could employ the `$_SERVER` superglobal to retrieve the path and place a conditional in the tag, passing it a class when it is active... Like so

```
<button class="EPButton <?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/home' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    Test button
</button
```

And in the CSS, you could go as follows:

```
.EPButton.active {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class in CSS

```
.active {
border: red solid 2px;
}
```

And add this class to the thing you want with a border on each page.